# >> operator on array of doubles?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

An issue with inputting data into arrays.

I'm using Dev C++ to execute and compile. Below is my code where the problem is:

```
for (int k=0;k<=149;k++){                                               // k - scanning through Y within single file #i
        for (int l=0;l<=199;l++){                                           // l - scanning through X within single file #i
            inp >> X[l]>> Y[k]>> Z>> Mx[l][k]>> My[l][k]>> Mz[l][k];
```

`Z` isn't missing a subscript, it's intended that way.

Full error code.:

```
[Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are
'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'double [2]')
```

Any advice is welcomed thank you.

Full Code:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4786)
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
string filename(int filenumber);
int main () {

    char *flnmptr;
    string str,tmpr;
    char flnm[50];

                                    !!! make sure that the array dimensions for input data are right - that might screw the output files
                                    dimensions are written in the 2nd header line of the input file

    double X[150], Y[200], Z[2], Mx[150][200][2], My[150][200][2], Mz[100][100][2], time;                               // data from file 
    // double hX[5001], vY[5001], hMx[5001],hMy[5001],hMz[5001], vMx[5001], vMy[5001], vMz[5001]; // data to be written to file
    //int xcnt, ycnt;            // variable to count how many values will be written to a file
    const int N=600;             //number of files
    //const int ptN=20;          // number of points in the line
    const double timestep=1e-14; // time step of files
    const double X0=2.749313e-1;      // X coordinate of line to read into vertical stripe output
    const double Y0=-9.614638e-1;      // Y coordinate of line to read into horizontal stripe output

ofstream outp("SWstripeCoupledCorner50difference10_120GHz.txt");        //opening output file 
    if (!outp){
        cout << "Can't open file.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<"Reading file #: ";

    outp.setf (ios::scientific ); // set the output format 

for (int i=1;i<=N;i++){
    std::strcpy(flnm,"");
    tmpr=filename(i);
    flnmptr=&tmpr[0];
    std::strcpy(flnm,flnmptr);

    ifstream inp;
    inp.open(flnm);                 // opens the file
    if(!inp)                        // if file couldn't be opened
    { 
        cerr << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::getline(inp,str,'\n');
    std::getline(inp,str,'\n');
    inp.setf (ios::scientific);

    for (int k=0;k<=149;k++){                                               // k - scanning through Y within single file #i
        for (int l=0;l<=199;l++){                                           // l - scanning through X within single file #i
            inp >> X[l]>> Y[k]>> Z>> Mx[l][k]>> My[l][k]>> Mz[l][k];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please paste the full code. What is `inp` type?

Comment: what are the exact types of `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `Mx`, `My`, `Mz`?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. From the error, it seems, that you are trying to read an array with `operator>>`. There's no such built-in operator, and you should consider reading elements of such array in a loop.

Comment: Ok. I'll post the full code

Comment: Ah I think I understand. I shall delve into literature explaining arrays and loop and attempt to apply to my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that

> `Z` isn't missing a subscript, it's intended that way.

But in your code `Z` is declared to be a `double[2]`.

The error message looks scary

> [Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are
>   'std::basic_istream::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream}' and 'double [2]')

but it essential means:

> [Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are
>   'std::ifstream' and 'double [2]')

You will either have to make `Z` a single `double` or access `Z` via an index like `inp >> Z[i]` I can't possible know which one you need in your program, so that is something you will have to think about or reduce the question to a [minimalistic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version.

Comment: Thank you for advice! I'll factor in Z. I guess I was a bit absent minded.

Comment: I don't receive the error message anymore. Thank you for your help.